# Recursively create directories in python while skipping existing directories

Tags: python, directory

I'm trying to create the following directories:

```
/autofs/homes/008/gwarner/test1/test2/

/autofs/homes/008/gwarner/test1/test3/
```

where `/autofs/homes/008/gwarner/` already exists and I don't have write access for all of `/autofs/homes/008/`. When I try running:

```
dir = '/autofs/homes/008/gwarner/test/test1/test4/test5/'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir, topdown = True):

    print root
```

I get no output at all.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've tried [`os.makedirs()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.makedirs), right?  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your requirements, but you say you want to:

> Recursively create directories

And the docs for `os.makedirs()` starts with:

> Recursive directory creation function.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the os.path.exists modules.

I would be careful and use both os.path.isdir and os.path.exists to check if the path is a directory before trying to write inside the directory and os.path.exists before overwriting a path.

For example:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.isdir('/home')
True
>>> os.path.isdir('/usr/bin')
True
>>> os.path.isdir('/usr/bin/python')
False
# writing a single, non-recursive path
>>> if not os.path.exists('/home/cinnamon'):
...     os.mkdir('/home/cinnamon')
# writing a single, recursive path
>>> if not os.path.exists('/home/alex/is/making/a/really/long/path'):
...     os.makedirs('/home/alex/is/making/a/really/long/path')
# now to script the latter
>>> paths = ['/home/alex/path/one', ...]
>>> for path in paths:
>>>     if not os.path.exists(path):
>>>        os.makedirs(path)
```

This way, you do not overwrite anything exists, you check if something is a directory before you write in the directory. By design, the system throws an OSError if the path exists, because it does not know HOW you want to handle it.

Do you want to overwrite the path (shutil.rmtree), do you want to store that the path has already been set, or do you want to just skip it? This is for you, the coder, to decide.

Comment: For the sake of making this easier for everyone I truncated the paths in my question. In reality, there are hundreds of directories I need to make that are much more complex than what I said above. That being said, manually typing in all of the paths isn't practical. I realize that I could write some code to split the paths and do what you said automatically but I feel like there is probably a function in os for that already.

Comment: Then you want os.walk. The same principle holds:

For each directory you want to add a path to, check if it's a directory first, then check if the directory you are making exists already, then make it if it does not exist.

os.path.exists answers your question. However, it's incomplete, unless if you know the dirname for every folder you are writing is, with 100% certainty, a directory.

Comment: How would that look? os.walk takes an existing directory, right? The input I have is the absolute path to a directory I need created, including the directories along the way that don't exist. If I pass that to os.walk() won't I get an error because it doesn't exist?

Comment: Then you just check os.path.exists for the absolute directory.

Comment: I'm confused on how that works. I tried:


    dir = '/autofs/homes/008/gwarner/test/test1/test4/test5/'

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir, topdown = True):

        print root`

And it didn't return anything. I need something that goes:

Does /autofs/ exist? Yes. Does /autofs/homes/ exist? Yes. Does /autofs/homes/008/ exist? Yes. Does /autofs/homes/008/gwarner/ exist? Yes. Does /autofs/homes/008/gwarner/test1/ exist? No. Create /autofs/homes/008/gwarner/test1/. Does /autofs/homes/008/gwarner/test1/test2/ exist? No. Create /autofs/homes/008/gwarner/test1/test2/. Stop.

Comment: Can you update your question with your new code and then your error message? If it's a permissions error, you can do an EAFP approach.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81033/discussion-between-alexander-huszagh-and-g-warner).